# Contribution shortcode is visible to logged in users

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, contribution-page

When I look at a Wordpress page with a CiviCRM contribution (inserted via *[civicrm component="contribution" id="6" mode="live" hijack="0"]* shortcode) as a logged in user I can see part of the shortcode under the payment confirmation button:

[image]

This does not appear for a annonymous user, but is visible as soon as the user logs in.

Any ideas how to remove this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please.  I assume the shortcode is appearing on the front-end.  When you entered the shortcode, did you enter it through the visual or text editor?  Is there anymore html content in the text editor and can you share it?  Have you tried loading the page in another Wordpress theme and if so, did you see the same result?

Comment: Yes, though not entire shortcode just the part you see in the image attached to the question. The shortcode was entered using visual editor and was working before. The problem appears on all the forms, regardless of the other content on the page and regardless of the applied theme. I am using the following shortcode:
[civicrm component="contribution" id="2" mode="live" hijack="1"]

Comment: I see that the shortcode stated in your comment is not the same as that in the question.  Could you perhaps reveal all the content shown in the text editor of the page in question?

Comment: Sorry for not being very precise - I know it can be annoying. In any case the problem appears on ANY page which uses CiviCRM shortcode. The one for case in question is 
[civicrm component="contribution" id="6" mode="live" hijack="0"]. There is nothing else in the text editor besides the shortcode.The page source will add this </div> ent="contribution" id="6" mode="live" hijack="0"]
     </div><!-- .entry-content --> just after the </script> statement.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why the additional code [ </div> ent="contribution" id="6" mode="live" hijack="0"] </div><!-- .entry-content -->] needs to be there, if the CiviCRM shortcode is already there in its entirity. I would take a copy of the existing code (in case you need to revert to it) and try deleting the code above to see what happens.  It would probably help if you could show the whole of the code that appears in the text editor (not the visual editor)

Comment: That's the confusing bit. For some reason this part is added to the HTML of the website even though there is only the shortcode in text editor, i.e. this is the problem.

Comment: That is odd!  Two other things cross my mind. Are you using the new Wordpress Gutenburg editor or the previous version and if you've tried both, do you get the same results?  Also, is there any other html in the CiviCRM contribution form itself, either in the introductory message or the Footer message, or in the Profile that your using (Pre-form and Post-form help)?

Comment: Yes I tried both - the results are the same regardless which option I choose. I've also tried to remove the intro message and the profile. None of that really helps.

Comment: Sorry but I think I've exhausted  any more ideas on this problem, short of you perhaps starting again with a brand new page to see if the problem re-occurs.
Maybe someone else could help with some further thoughts on this.

Comment: Well thanks anyway. I'll try to reproduce this from scratch and see if the problem persists